# pandas multi-index slicing based on number of items in a level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-indexed series that I'm trying to print all values for level 0 if there is more than one item at level 1.  For example, take this series:

```
   match
0  0         apple
1  0        orange
   1          pear
   2        banana
```

I don't care about apple since it's the only entry at level 0, index 0.  Since there are three items at level 0, index 1, I want to print them all.  The best I've gotten is `print(fruit.loc[(fruit.index.get_level_values('match') != 0)])`, but that will only give me pear and banana, not orange.  It seems like I should be able to get the level 0 indices out of there somehow and pass those to `.loc()`, but I'm not having any luck.

To create the series above:

```py
arrays = [[0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2]]
multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('', 'match'))

fruit = pd.Series(data=('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana'), index=multi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a mask by using groupby on level 0 and `transform` with `count` to find level 1 has more than 1 item

```
m = fruit.groupby(level=0).transform('count') > 1
fruit[m]

Out[421]:
   match
1  0        orange
   1          pear
   2        banana
dtype: object
```

---

Another way to create mask `m` from @ALolz

```
m = fruit.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)
```

Comment: @oppressionslayer: this solution is for 2-level multiindex of the provided sample. If the sample has 3 or n-levels multiindex, the solution would need modification accordingly.

Comment: Both of those methods work on my real dataset, but the `get_level_values()` method is really clever.  It took me a few minutes to understand what's actually going on, but if anybody runs across this and is unclear:  The level 0 index will show up in `get_level_values()` once for every item in the level 1 index (`'match'` in this case), so if there is more than one item in level 1, the level 0 index will show up more than once.  Filtering it through `duplicated()` will return only the level 0 indices that have more than one item.